# Unexpected behaviour when trying to use String.split("\\?")

Tags: java, string, split

So I have a string that is like this:

```
"Some text here?Some number here"
```

and I need to split those, I am using `String.split("\\?")`, but if I have a string like this:

```
"This is a string with, comma?1234567"
```

I have it splitted in the comma(`,`) too. And if I have this String:

```
"That´s a problem here?123456"
```

It also splits on `´`, So how can I fix this?

Comment: can you put the text example in a code block so we can distinguish between the question and the example?

Comment: DO you need to split a string by several characters? So, the String "test1?test2,test3" comes into "test1", "test2", "test3"?

Comment: what version of java are you using? I do not get this problem.....

Comment: (I doubt there is a java version that will show your problem....)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I am not seeing this behaviour: (nor would I expect to)

```
String s ="hello?1000";

String[] fields = s.split("\\?");

for (String field : fields) {
   System.out.println(field);
}
```

yields:

hello

1000

Introducing a comma "," or an apostrophe "'" doesn't make any difference to the split:

```
String s ="he,llo?1000";
```

yields:

he,llo

1000

```
String s ="he'llo?1000";
```

yields:

he'llo

1000

The spilt also works fine if you have any spaces in your input string. I can only suggest that your regex is not what you think it is!

Answer (score 2):

this is the solution: (EDIT: it's even simpler)

```
public static Pair<String,String> getSplittedByQuestionMark(String term){
    String[] list=term.split("[?]");
    return new Pair<String,String>(list[0],list[1]);
}
```

i tested it:

```
@Test
public void testGetSplittedByQuestionMark(){
    ArrayList<String> terms=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Pair<String,String>> expected=new ArrayList<Pair<String,String>>();
    terms.add("test?a");
    terms.add("test?20");
    terms.add("test, with comma?ab10");
    expected.add(new Pair<String,String>("test","a"));
    expected.add(new Pair<String,String>("test","20"));
    expected.add(new Pair<String,String>("test, with comma","ab10"));
    for(int i=0;i<terms.size();i++){
        Pair<String,String> answer = StringStandardRegex.getSplittedByQuestionMark(terms.get(i));
        assertTrue("answer="+answer.getFirst(),answer.getFirst().equals(expected.get(i).getFirst()));
        assertTrue("answer="+answer.getSecond(),answer.getSecond().equals(expected.get(i).getSecond()));
    }

}
```

[EDIT after remark below] I have added a test, Now I don;t see what's the problem, this works as well (and is even more simpel):

```
@Test
public void testGetSplittedByQuestionMarkNotUsingRegex(){
    ArrayList<String> terms=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Pair<String,String>> expected=new ArrayList<Pair<String,String>>();
    terms.add("test?a");
    terms.add("test?20");
    terms.add("test, with comma?ab10");
    expected.add(new Pair<String,String>("test","a"));
    expected.add(new Pair<String,String>("test","20"));
    expected.add(new Pair<String,String>("test, with comma","ab10"));
    for(int i=0;i<terms.size();i++){
        String[] answer=terms.get(i).split("\\?");
        assertTrue("answer="+answer[0],answer[0].equals(expected.get(i).getFirst()));
        assertTrue("answer="+answer[1],answer[1].equals(expected.get(i).getSecond()));
    }

}
```

Comment: In my other solution a more generic answer is given for this kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typical regex problem.
I am using this for example to split

```
name (code)
```

into a pair with the name and the code separate:

```
RE regex = new RE("(.*) \\W(.*)\\W");
if(!regex.match(term)){
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("the given term does not match the regelar expression:'NAME (ID)'");
}
Pair<String,String> pair=new Pair<String,String>(regex.getParen(1),regex.getParen(2));
return pair;
```

Comment: actually regex is the problem with your solution:

Comment: \\? is not for the question mark, but the regex for more symbols

Comment: This might help: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @michael: The question mark is escaped (note the \\ before the ?). A double backslash is used for escaping instead of single backslash because it is a string literal in Java source code.

Comment: See my other answer, that is a simpeler solution for this problem (also tested it for you)

Comment: @michael: See Richard's answer.

Comment: You are right, i missed the simpeler solution: there is no problem (I agree)